# How to format a String object in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a `HashMap` with endpoints:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, Ord, Eq, PartialOrd, PartialEq, Hash)]
enum Endpoint {
    OauthToken,
    Disciplines,
    PublicTournaments,
    MyTournaments,
    Matches,
}

lazy_static! {
    static ref API_EP: HashMap<Endpoint, &'static str> = {
        let mut m: HashMap<Endpoint, &'static str> = HashMap::new();
        m.insert(Endpoint::OauthToken, "/oauth/v2/token");
        m.insert(Endpoint::Disciplines, "/v1/disciplines");
        m.insert(Endpoint::PublicTournaments, "/v1/tournaments");
        m.insert(Endpoint::MyTournaments, "/v1/me/tournaments");
        m.insert(Endpoint::Matches, "/v1/tournaments/{}/matches");
        m
    };
}
```

As you may see, the map item which is accessible by `Endpoint::Matches` key returns a string which needs to be formatted, however, I don't see a way of doing this.

I've tried to use `format!` macro but it needs string literals but not an object so it does not work. I tried to search the solution over the internet and rust std library but I was unable to find it. Is there any way to do this?

For clarification why `format!` does not work:

```
error: format argument must be a string literal.
   --> src/lib.rs:249:31
    |
249 |         let address = format!(get_ep_address(Endpoint::Matches)?, id.0);
```

`get_ep_address(Endpoint::Matches)?` is not a string literal so it can't work.

I would also like to know how to format both `&str` and `String` types.

Comment: @erip: That's exactly the difference between a literal and a NOT literal.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Whoops, overlooked that bit, hehe.

Comment: Very interesting. It appears that you will need a literal format string -- everything seems to revolve around `format_args!()`, which imposes this limitation. It actually makes sense because the compiler ensures the validity of the formatting operation, it cannot be delayed to run-time.

Comment: I [used this a while ago](https://github.com/vitiral/strfmt) while playing around with string formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `format!` macro expects a literal because it invokes compiler magic ([`format_args!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.format_args.html)) to check the format at compile and ensure that its arguments implement the necessary trait. For example `{}` requires that the argument implements `Display`, as described in [Formatting traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#formatting-traits).

You *might* be able to cobble something together by reaching to [`Formatter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html) directly, but it means parsing the `str` yourself.

---

*Note: Rust does not feature reflection, so checking whether a type implements a given trait at runtime is not easy...*